# Get a readyState of 4 and a status of 200 plus a statusText of "OK" and success function still doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to get my mail form to work properly and i keep having problems getting the ajax success function to get called on. I have read many artricles and questions that are close to what i am talking about and have yet to find the answer so please do not revert me to another post or say it is a duplicate question. I Get a readyState of 4 and a status of 200 plus a statusText of "OK" and success function still doesn't get called. I have no idea what is preventing it from being called. the email info gets sent to my email perfectly fine but again the success function is not being called. Any help would be amazing and greatly appreciated.

Here is my EMAIL.php file:

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    # Is the OS Windows or Mac or Linux 
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3)=='WIN')) { 
      $eol="\r\n"; 
    } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3)=='MAC')) { 
      $eol="\r"; 
    } else { 
      $eol="\n"; 
    } 

    //CHECK IF MAIL HAS BEEN SENT AND IF EMAIL FIELD IS FILLED.
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

        $email_to = 'me@example.com';
        $email_subject = 'Website Change Request';

        if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
            !isset($_POST['email']) ||
            !isset($_POST['message'])) {
            died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
        }

         // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $em_name = $_POST["name"];
        $em_email = $_POST["email"];
        $em_message = $_POST["message"];
        $em_phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $em_website = $_POST['website'];
        $em_hear = $_POST['hear'];
        $em_startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
        $em_budget = $_POST['budget'];

        $error_message = "";
        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

        if(!preg_match($email_exp,$em_email)) {
            $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        }

        if(!preg_match($string_exp,$em_name)) {
            $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        }

        if(strlen($em_message) < 2) {
            $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
        }

        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            echo $error_message;
        }

        $mime_boundary = md5(time()); 

        $email_headers = "From: " . $em_email . $eol;
        $email_headers .= "Reply-To: " . $em_email . $eol;
        $email_headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion().$eol; 
        $email_message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$eol; 
        $email_message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol; 

        // Build the email content.
        $email_message =  "Name: " . $em_name . $eol;
        $email_message .= "Message: " . $em_message . $eol;
        $email_message .= "Budget: " . $em_budget . $eol;
        $email_message .= "Start Date: " . $em_startdate . $eol;
        $email_message .= "How did you hear about us?: " . $em_hear . $eol;
        $email_message .= "Email: " . $em_email . $eol;
        $email_message .= "Phone: " . $em_phone . $eol;
        $email_message .= "Website: " . $em_website . $eol;

        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $email_headers); 
        echo "MAIL INFO: "+mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $email_headers);
        echo "message was succesfull!";
    }
    else{
        echo "not working form";
    }
?>
```

Javascript:

```
          emailValidation: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:0},"slow");
            var valid = '';
            var name = $("#f_name").val();
            var email = $("#f_email").val();
            var message = $("#f_message").val();
            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

            if(name === '' || name.length <= 2){
                valid += '<p class="error">Name must be longer than 2 char.</p>';
            }
            if(message === '' || message.length <= 5){
                valid += '<p class="error">Message must be longer than 5 char.</p>';
            }
            if (!(email).match(emailReg)){
                valid += '<p class="error">Invalid Email</p>';
            }
            if (valid !== ''){
                $('#form-messages').html(''+valid+'').fadeIn();
            }
            else {
                // var formData = $("#contact").serialize();//Value for sanitized form values to be paased to email.php. Value returns an array
                 portfolio.submitEmail();
            }
        },
        submitEmail: function(){
            var formData = $("#contact").serializeArray();
            console.log('Form DATA: '+formData);//Value for sanitized form values to be paased to email.php. Value returns an array
            //$('#form-messages').html("Proccessing...").fadeIn('slow');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'mailer.php',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    $("#contact").fadeOut('slow').remove();
                    $('#form-messages').removeClass();
                    $('#form-messages').empty().addClass('success');
                    $('#form-messages').html('<p class="success">Message has been sent succesfully! Thank you '+ $('#f_name').val() +', a response will be returned in less than one business day.</p>');
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(response);
                },
                complete: function(response){
                    $("#contact").fadeOut('slow').remove();
                    $('#form-messages').removeClass();
                    $('#form-messages').empty().addClass('success');
                    $('#form-messages').html('<p class="success">Message has been sent succesfully! Thank you '+ $('#f_name').val() +', a response will be returned in less than one business day.</p>');
                    console.log('complete');
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(error);

                },
            });
        },
```

Comment: Post your JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be in your `jQuery.ajax` settings object. You are specifying a `dataType` of `'json'`, but your `EMAIL.php` does not output JSON, it outputs plain text by the look of it. Since jQuery is unable to parse the response as JSON, it will call the `error` callback, instead of the `success` callback.

To correct this, specify `dataType: "text"` instead, or remove the property altogether.

#### Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'mailer.php',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(response){
        $("#contact").fadeOut('slow').remove();
        $('#form-messages').removeClass();
        $('#form-messages').empty().addClass('success');
        $('#form-messages').html('<p class="success">Message has been sent succesfully! Thank you '+ $('#f_name').val() +', a response will be returned in less than one business day.</p>');
        console.log('success');
        console.log(response);
    },
    complete: function(response){
        $("#contact").fadeOut('slow').remove();
        $('#form-messages').removeClass();
        $('#form-messages').empty().addClass('success');
        $('#form-messages').html('<p class="success">Message has been sent succesfully! Thank you '+ $('#f_name').val() +', a response will be returned in less than one business day.</p>');
        console.log('complete');
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log('error');
        console.log(error);

    },
});
```

Also, to avoid a PHP strict warning, change this line:

```
$email_message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$eol;
```

To this:

```
$email_message = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$eol;
```

You never declared this variable before appending, which will cause a strict warning.

Comment: I came so close to trying that but never ended up doing it obviously. Thank you so much. changing dataType to 'text' instead of 'json' worked like a charm.

Comment: why do i still get a responseText  of <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: email_message in <b>/home4/travism2/public_html/travis/mailer.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />

Comment: their is nothing wrong with my $emial_message and the email is sent correctly.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. everything works perfectly and i understand what i did wrong.